# Meteor ios blank screen on device and simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, meteor-ios

My Meteor app runs fine in browser and android device however on ios-device and simulator I am always stuck with a blank white screen after launch. Xcode is new to me so i don't know if it is something i am doing wrong? However I followed the ios testing directions to the letter. I also tried numerous fixes my google is riddled with last seen dates on every keyword search i can think of. My Safari developer console shows these output errors pasted below.......Has anyone else seen this problem or know how to fix it?

(substituted my ip address for http://000.000.00.000:3000/ for obvious security reasons. also note: body element is empty but updates the iphone screen if i edit html in console. It seems like my homepage is never rendered)

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')
    index.js (elmarti_video-chat.js:1042)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    index.js (elmarti_video-chat.js:453)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    index.js (elmarti_video-chat.js:53)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    (anonymous function) (elmarti_video-chat.js:6319)
    Global Code (elmarti_video-chat.js:6326)
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://000.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'VideoCallServices')
    (anonymous function) (app.js:1950)
    (anonymous function) (blaze.js:3398)
    _withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js:3744)
    fireCallbacks (blaze.js:3394)
    (anonymous function) (blaze.js:3474)
    fireCallbacks (blaze.js:2014)
    nonreactive (tracker.js:640)
    (anonymous function) (blaze.js:2011)
    _withCurrentView (blaze.js:2271)
    _fireCallbacks (blaze.js:2010)
    _createView (blaze.js:2028)
    _materializeView (blaze.js:2073)
    materializeDOMInner (blaze.js:1532)
    _materializeDOM (blaze.js:1474)
    (anonymous function)
    _materializeDOM (blaze.js:1483)
    (anonymous function) (blaze.js:2113)
    nonreactive (tracker.js:640)
    _materializeView (blaze.js:2079)
    render (blaze.js:2370)
    insert (iron_dynamic-template.js:518)
    insert (iron_router.js:1639)
    maybeAutoInsertRouter (iron_router.js:1629)
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://000.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://00.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://000.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://000.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
[Error] Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (_timesync, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://000.000.00.000:3000/_timesync due to access control checks.
```

Comment: `Origin http://localhost:12952 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` this message basically tells you that you need to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header from the server, to allow connections from other IPs. Check [this link](https://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html).

Comment: hi @AlejandroIván thank you for the help...... I've already had the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set. Even after adding the links example fix I am still only getting a blank white screen.

Comment: @GeekBoy Did you ever solve this? I'm getting a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and I solved it of the following way:

1. Remove `node_modules` folder
2. Execute `meteor reset`
3. Remove `.cache` folder
4. Install dependencies again (I used yarn).
5. And done!!! The app should be run in simulator and device.

Tested on:

- Mac OS 11.1 Big Sur
- XCode 12.3
- Meteor 1.12.1
- Front-end is built with Vue and Vuetify using akryum package.
- Simulator with iOS 14.3 on iPhone 12 Pro Max
- Physical device with iOS 14.3 on iPhone SE

I hope this help you as well.